# Download a page only with the link?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I want to know is there any way to download a page only with the link.

For example : link and at the end we got the source code.

Here is my pseudo code :

/* 1- create a variable and save the link of the current page in it 2- download the saved link source code in a HTML file */

Comment: Please clearly define what you mean by "page". Do you mean just whatever the response is when requesting that resource? (for webpages, this is usually just the html). Do you mean everything the html requests as well? Download to where?

Comment: @starball just the html is enough save it in a folder anywhere

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: If you haven't already, would you mind taking some time to read ["How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/11107541)? I think you will find it useful in adjusting your self-expectations to be in line with the rest of the community's.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML download attribute e.g. `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`